# Different value of date display between database and data table

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, date, jdbc

I have a problem with display of dates from Oracle database in a Java webapplication using a JSF datatable. The displayed date differs from the date in the database.

Here are some examples:

```
in oracle: 24-APR-87 display in datatable: Apr 23, 1987  
in oracle: 01-JAN-10 display in datatable: Dec 31, 2009  
in oracle: 13-MAR-89 display in datatable: Mar 12, 1989
```

Here is my Java source code:

```
public Result getTable() {  
    try {  
        Class.forName(dbDriver);  
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
        ps = con.createStatement();  
        String query = "SELECT * from " + getTableName();  
        rs = ps.executeQuery(query);  
        return(ResultSupport.toResult(rs));  
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        return(null);
    }  
}
```

What is the cause and solution for my problem?

Comment: Is the second example supposed to be `01-JAN-10`, so each jsf date appears one day behind? Also, how are you viewing the Oracle dates - SQL*Plus on the same server, SQL Developer, ...? It looks like a timezone issue, maybe, either in the connection to the database or in how you're manipulating the retrieved date once you get it back.

Comment: yes, you are right it's 01-JAN-2010, i don't familiar with these databse, it's first time for me use it at my program..  can u help me to expalin about timezone issue, or maybe an example about that and about connection to the database and manipulating the retrieved date?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 1):

Oracle stores dates using an internal format that bears no relationship to how it's formatted for display.

What you're seeing is two different date formats being used by different frontends.

To force a query to use the format of your choice, it is best to use `TO_CHAR`, e.g.:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(mydatecolumn,'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM mytable;
```

Comment: I want my code can be used for all tables . how do I re-construct my code above to continue to be used by all the tables, but also applying TO_CHAR code?

Comment: The code you have in your question appears to return a result set without converting the dates to strings - perhaps the conversion is being done by the caller?

Comment: here is my jsf-config:  
 <managed-bean>  
        <managed-bean-name>dataAll</managed-bean-name>  
        <managed-bean-class>polimatPackage.Connection.getData</managed-bean-class>  
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>  
    </managed-bean>  
   
 and here is my jsp code:  
 <h:outputText id="dateBirth" value="#{dataAll.dateBirth}" />  
   
 can you help me to explain or make a solution for these code...

Comment: so all your tables have a `dateBirth` column? I'm not sure that your generic "getTable" function is the best way here, but I'm not familiar with JSF so will say no more...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `f:convertDateTime` converter with the JSF output and set the correct `timeZone` attribute for it.
Example (edit):

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.myDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime timeZone="America/Los_Angeles" type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: can you give me an example for that?